# JavaScript Vending Machine Check if Item exist else new and stock change

Tags: javascript, html

I m building a vending machine in JavaScript to learn it. But now I have a  problem.
All values are from 3 input fields which i hand over.
So I want to build a function to check If a snack is in already existing. If it's exist it should add the new price and the existing stock will added with the stock out of my input field.
If the snack is not in the machine it will be added. This is what I already have.

```
 var selection = [
        {name: "fanta", price: 1.60, stock: 4},
        {name: "cola", price: 1.70, stock: 3},
        {name: "nuts", price: 1.10, stock: 8},
        {name: "mars", price: 1.20, stock: 2},
        {name: "snickers", price: 1.20, stock: 5}
    ];




function new_snack_snack(selection){


var new_price_input = document.getElementById("new_price").value;
var new_stock_input = document.getElementById("new_stock").value;
var new_snack_input = document.getElementById("new_snack").value;


selection.push({name: new_snack_input, price: new_price_input, stock: new_stock_input});

console.log(selection);

    document.getElementById("snack_table_output").innerHTML = create_table();

    }
```

Comment: *"I want to build a function to check If a snack is in already existing"*: what is holding you back doing so? What is the problem you faced? Where did you get stuck? The code you shared does not show any attempt at implementing that...

Comment: I would use an object rather than an array for `selection`. Then use the name as the key so that no duplicate snacks are allowed. The new new stock and price would be overwritten if it exists, or added if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var selection = [{
    name: "fanta",
    price: 1.60,
    stock: 4
  },
  {
    name: "cola",
    price: 1.70,
    stock: 3
  },
  {
    name: "nuts",
    price: 1.10,
    stock: 8
  },
  {
    name: "mars",
    price: 1.20,
    stock: 2
  },
  {
    name: "snickers",
    price: 1.20,
    stock: 5
  }
];




function new_snack_snack(selection) {


  var new_price_input = document.getElementById("new_price").value;
  var new_stock_input = document.getElementById("new_stock").value;
  var new_snack_input = document.getElementById("new_snack").value;


  if (!selection.find(item => item.name === new_snack_input) {
      selection.push({
        name: new_snack_input,
        price: new_price_input,
        stock: new_stock_input
      });
    }

    console.log(selection);

    document.getElementById("snack_table_output").innerHTML = create_table();

  }
```

Comment: Thank for the code snip i try to implement it but i get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Comment: @whoamiidontknowit Is selection defined?

Comment: So I fixed it now it's working thanks. Can you help with the other problem I have. It's if the snack exist it should change the price and the stock will change too. Stock will be the input value added with the current stock.

Comment: @whoamiidontknowit Can you create new question?

Comment: OK i will create a new question

Comment: i created a new question